# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken after uploading online

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating web app using laravel 5.
After completing app, I uploaded the app online but I am getting this error(it is working in localhost)
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67

I searched online and found many answers
famous one

I already have that in my file.
It is working 100% fine in localhost and not working after I uploaded it online only so suggested solutions are not working.

I have checked env file,session file but all seems ok but none of the forms seems to be working or giving same error
Even cache,session folder has correct permission.

So, I don't know what to do.

Any suggestions where should i look into?

Edit:
I disabled CSRF as temporary measure but I am being redirected to login page again(not being redirect to correct page)

Comment: would be helpful if you can post some part of the code

Comment: @RajeshHegde None of the form is working and problem is it is working fine in localhost but not after uploading so i think problem is related to some settings somewhere rather than code.

Comment: Try to manually verify the csrf token being generated and the current one in the session.

Comment: @Sandeesh It looks same as on now 
http://i.imgur.com/CnwWwXV.jpg
using {{ csrf_token() }} for hidden form field

Comment: Try clearing all config, cache and compiled classes. `php artisan config:clear` `php artisan route:clear` `php artisan view:clear` `php artisan clear-compiled`. Also verify the session storage used and if you're using files by default, check manually if the session files are being generated.

Comment: @Sandeesh I tried this in auth controller's function(ran ok) but still is not working--same error
Artisan::call('config:clear');
Artisan::call('route:clear');
Artisan::call('view:clear');
Artisan::call('clear-compiled');

Comment: Since this runs fine on your localhost, it must be related to sessions. Either your sessions are expiring too soon or they're not being stored properly. Can you check your session expiry value and other session config in `session.php`

Comment: @Sandeesh     'lifetime' => 360, 'expire_on_close' => false, in session. I am also clueless what to do. Don't know what is causing the problem and where to look

Comment: Which platform have you uploaded on? Personally I had the exact same problem when I uploaded my laravel app online on _Heroku_, and the .env file is not uploaded there, so I had to set up the Environment variables on the server manually.

Answer (score 0):

Add,`{{ csrf_field() }}` inside your `<form>`

For more information, visit [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf)

On, **Server:**

Edit your key-value in session.php as `secure => false` & `'http_only' => true`. Also, check if the session driver is "file", if it's cookie then change to "file" or vice versa.

also, regenerate your app key with: `php artisan key:generate`

See, if that works.

Comment: Thank you but I have already said I had that inside the form. Plus problem is it is working fine offline but not working AFTER i upload it to online. So may be problem is related to some settings which i need to change after online upload. I have imported the db file. Is settings for this csrf check saved somewhere in db by default in laravel?

Comment: After making changes in php.ini file on your server, have you restarted your apache?

Comment: I had done all the things said including those false and true to no avail. It is working in localhost but not online. I am not able to restart the apache as I am in shared hosting online. The sessions files are being written to folders but some reasons it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after 2 days of cluelessness I have been able to solve it.
The problem was:
cookie was not being written so because of that for each query new session id was being created.

why cookie was not being written

there was some silly white space after closing tag of one of the config file.(not before but after ?>)
maybe because of that there was "header already sent" error (but was showing in the error log)

Anyway removed those white spaces and it was all working but it was so tedious looking at each file searching for the whitespaces..

Answer (score 0):

If you are on https make sure secure session cookie is enabled. Your browser wont read the cookie otherwise. It works locally because you are using an http environment.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by generating a new app key and running the cache clearing commands listed in Sandeesh's comment.

`php artisan key:generate`

`php artisan config:clear`

`php artisan route:clear`

`php artisan view:clear`

`php artisan clear-compiled`